# Better method to find the second largest element in ruby on rails active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am using this query to find the 2nd largest element. I am making query on `value` column.

```
Booking.where("value < ?", Booking.maximum(:value)).last
```

Is there any better query than this? Or any alternative to this.

PS - `value` is not unique. There could be two elements with same value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
Booking.select("DISTINCT value").order('value DESC').offset(1).limit(1)
```

Which will generate this query :

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT value FROM "bookings"  ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: this also will work :

`Booking.select("DISTINCT value").order("value DESC OFFSET 1 LIMIT 1")`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `offset` and `last`:

```
Booking.order(:value).offset(1).last
```

Which will produce following SQL statement:

```
SELECT  `bookings`.* FROM `bookings`  
ORDER BY `bookings`.`value` DESC 
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
```

Comment: Tried.
What if there are two elements with equal value and both the elements has the largest value. `offset(1)` may not work

Comment: You should specify this requirement because _the 2nd largest element_ and _the 2nd largest unique element_ is not the same.

Comment: for none unique maximum  elements  problem I think specifying DISTINCT option in the query will solve it.